# Probability of catching a pokemon after N tries

Tags: probability

I had this question while I was playing Pokemon shuffle.

To put things in perspective, each time you beat a pokemon in this game, you get a chance to catch it. There's something called "catchability" index, and it's what determines if you will catch the pokemon or not. This "catchability" is actually just the probability of catching said pokemon expressed in percentage.

My question is, given a pokemon that has a catchability of 30% (that is, you have 0.3 change of catching it), what is the probability of catching it after 5 tries?

I'd like a generalized answer in the case of a pokemon that has a catchability of C after N number of tries.

Comment: Try thinking about the probability you don't catch it after five tries, then use the fact that $P(A) = 1-P(A^c)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the probability of catch is constant at $C$ on every try, and assuming the results of each try are independent, then you will succeed on try $N$ exactly when the first $N-1$ tries result in failure and the $N$th results in success. So the chance that it takes *exactly* $N$ tries to catch is $(1-C)^{N-1}C$. The chance that it takes *more* than $N$ tries is the chance that the first $N$ tries are all failures, which is $(1-C)^N$.