# Probability of finding same pokemon

Tags: probability, geometry, circles

A and B are playing pokemon go, their phones detect pokemons within 1 meter range. A and B are 1 meter apart. A finds a pokemon,  what is the probability B finds the same pokemon ?

Here is a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220363/probability-of-catching-a-pokemon-after-n-tries). But in this case, probability are based on geometry.

Comment: Is this supposed to be somehow related to the overlapping area of the two circles? It is not so clear to me. If, say, in an area fo 300 square meters there are just Mareeps, then the probability is $100\%$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes it is related to overlapping area.